# add basic auth to express rest api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, basic-authentication

so I have rest api where i store user data in mongoDB, I want to add basic auth to my api but I'm stuck, I want to check if user is authorised on some paths, for example on /update, if user is auth perfom request, if not send that user is not authorized

my code where I store user is db

```
  const addUser = async (req, res) => {
  const checknick = await User.find({ nickname: req.body.nickname }) //checks if user exists with nickname
  if (checknick.length !== 0) {
    return res.send({
      message: 'user already exists, please use another nickname',
    })
  }

  const secretInfo = await hash(req.body.password).catch((err) =>
    res.send('password is required!')
  )
  const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    surname: req.body.surname,
    nickname: req.body.nickname,
    password: secretInfo.password,
    salt: secretInfo.salt,
  })
  user.save((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err)
    }
    res.send('user added sucesessfully')
  })
}
```

and where I verify user

```
const verify = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ nickname: req.body.nickname })
  if (!user) {
    return
  }

  const { password } = await hash(req.body.password, user.salt).catch((err) =>
    res.send('password is required')
  )

  const verifiedUser = await User.findOne({
    nickname: req.body.nickname,
    password: password,
  })

  if (!verifiedUser) {
    return false
  }
  return true
}
```

and finally login logic

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
  const access = await verify(req, res)

  // console.log(req.headers)
  if (access) {
    res.send('logged in')
    console.log(req.headers)
    return
  }
  return res.status(401).send('failed to login')
}
```

everything works but I want to use authorizatuon header to send user and password information

Answer (score 0):

This is how to restrict a route add this middleware function before the
route you want to restrict like this:

```js
app.post("/update", restrictTo("admin"));
```

Every user must have a role to authorize. here I am handling error with a global error handler but you can handle error another way:

```js
exports.restrictTo = (...roles) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        if (!roles.includes(req.user.role))
            return next(
                new AppError('You dont have permission to do this action', 403)
            );
        next();
    };
};
```